# WPF Datagrid doesn't deselect hidden items

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with several items, and my program's logic depends on the selected rows.

When I click on a row, the usual behavior is to selected the clicked row and deselect all others. However, if I click on a row, then scroll down to the point it becomes not visible anymore, and then click on another row, it will keep the 2 rows selected.

I know that a solution using MouseDown events to manipulate the selected items would work, but I wanted to prevent doing that.

**Edit:** I need it to be SelectionMode="Extended".

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior, but here's a test to run for more info. Set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on your DataGrid and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: It was set to true before, however the behavior continues the same.

Comment: @AndréSantaló: I know, that it may be too late for party, but I've faced with the same issue, and looks like there's a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24149635/580053

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable multi selection behaviour set the `SelectionMode` to *Single*

`<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single"`

Comment: I need it to be SelectionMode="Extended", and unfortunately even changing it to Single doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AndréSantaló your question is not clear enough then, What do you want to do actually ?

Comment: My problem is that when I click on a row it doesn't deselect the rows that are not visible, only deselecting the visible ones at the moment.