# DataGrid doesn't deselect hidden items properly when SelectionMode="Extended"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have an issue with WPF `DataGrid`, which drives me crazy.
Let's consider this view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected 
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}'s IsSelected new value is: {1}", Name, value);
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool isSelected;

    // INPC implementation
}
```

... this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
            <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is selected" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...and this code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private IList<ViewModel> GenerateViewModels()
    {
        var viewModels = new List<ViewModel>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            viewModels.Add(new ViewModel
            {
                Id = i,
                Name = string.Format("Item {0}", i)
            });
        }

        return viewModels;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = GenerateViewModels();
    }
}
```

**Case 1.**

- Select Item 0. Item 0 is selected, check box is checked.
- Scroll grid's content to hide Item 0. Let the Item 6 be on top of visible area.
- Select Item 10. Item 10 is selected, check box is checked.
- Scroll up to Item 0.
- Select Item 0. Item 10 is selected, check box is **not** checked.

Debug output:

```
Item 0's IsSelected new value is: True
Item 0's IsSelected new value is: False
Item 10's IsSelected new value is: True
Item 10's IsSelected new value is: False
```

[image: Screenshot:]

**Case 2.**

- Restart application.
- Select several items on top of grid (e.g., three first items). Items are selected, check boxes are checked.
- Scroll grid's content to hide Item 0. Let the Item 6 be on top of visible area.
- Select Item 10. Item 10 is selected, check box is checked.
- Scroll up to Item 0.
- Item 0 and Item 1 **are still checked**. Item 2 isn't checked. All of three first items aren't selected.

Debug output:

```
Item 0's IsSelected new value is: True
Item 1's IsSelected new value is: True
Item 2's IsSelected new value is: True
Item 2's IsSelected new value is: False
Item 10's IsSelected new value is: True
```

[image: Screenshot:]

The problem is reproducing, when the selection mode is extended. When it is single, everything works fine.

**Questions:**
1. Am I missing something?
2. Anybody knows a workaround?

**UPDATE**.

I've added `SelectionChanged` event handler for the grid:

```
    private void MyGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems.Cast<ViewModel>())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("** Item {0} is added to selection.", item.Id);
            }
        }
        if (e.RemovedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems.Cast<ViewModel>())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("** Item {0} is removed from selection.", item.Id);
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Debug output says, that `SelectedItems` collection is updated **properly**. E.g., for the first case output will be:

```
Item 0's IsSelected new value is: True
** Item 0 is added to selection.
Item 0's IsSelected new value is: False
Item 10's IsSelected new value is: True
** Item 10 is added to selection.
** Item 0 is removed from selection.
Item 10's IsSelected new value is: False
** Item 0 is added to selection.
** Item 10 is removed from selection.
```

But the bound data property `IsSelected` isn't updated!

Comment: Nothing much to add, except that this same problem is driving me mad too. It's totally counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, one workaround is found, and its related to the question's update.
Let's modify `SelectionChanged` event handler a little:

```
    private void MyGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems.Cast<ViewModel>())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("** Item {0} is added to selection.", item.Id);

                if (!item.IsSelected)
                {
                    // if bound data item still isn't selected, fix this
                    item.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.RemovedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems.Cast<ViewModel>())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("** Item {0} is removed from selection.", item.Id);

                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    // if bound data item still is selected, fix this
                    item.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But it's definitely a bug in `DataGrid`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and I think you need to set the isSelected to false to both condition. It works for me. But thanks for the initial solution! It helped me a lot.

```
private void MyGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems.Cast<ViewModel>())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("** Item {0} is added to selection.", item.Id);

                if (!item.IsSelected)
                {
                    // if bound data item still isn't selected, fix this
                    item.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.RemovedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems.Cast<ViewModel>())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("** Item {0} is removed from selection.", item.Id);

                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    // if bound data item still is selected, fix this
                    item.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Nope. Setting `IsSelected` to `false` when inspecting `AddedItems` is wrong. This means, that item, which is selected visually (that is, it is highlighted by `DataGrid`) will have `IsSelected == false`. This makes data out of sync - data item must present in `DataGrid.SelectedItems` *only* when `IsSelected == true`.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm trying to solve the same issue but my problem is when all of the items are initially IsSelected = true. When I select one row, the hidden items does not get deselected. Do you have an idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Hmm... Looks like virtualization issue - since item containers for invisible items are not created yet, `DG` just ignores them. At the moment, I can't propose some solution, will look later.

Comment: The only thing, that comes to mind, is to handle this as special case - that is, when selection was changed from several items to single item, find all items with `IsSelected == true` (except selected item), and set `IsSelected` to false.